# Capacitor circuit simplification

Tags: voltage, capacitor, parallel, series

I am unsure if I have simplified this circuit correctly, therefore I am unsure how to write Vo in terms of V1. Please let me know if I have simplified this correctly.[image]

Answer (score 1):

You simplified the circuit correctly. However, the simplified circuit no longer contains terminals a and b. In your last circuit, you show terminals a and b as being across the voltage source Vi and its series capacitor. From the original circuit, this is clearly not the case. Basically you simplified in the wrong direction.  You need to start on the left side of the circuit and, through the use of capacitive voltage dividers, work your way down to the right.  You should wind up with a voltage source in series with a capacitor at terminals a and b. Since there is no load (i=0), the voltage source (which will be a function of Vi and C) will be equal to Vo.

Comment: so I can simply put those three capacitors above in series?

Comment: No. C on left and 42C/43 are in parallel; and this parallel combination is in series with C connected to V+. Also, a & b in the final diagram are not the same as a & b in the original. You need to work back through the circuit to determine the currents and voltages in all the branches.

Comment: So in the beginning, I can place the C on the left to the very right?

Answer (score 0):

It might help a little to re-draw the schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4s77H.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I don't know if you are familiar with nodal analysis. But the following is just using nodal analysis except instead of current it is dealing with capacitor charge conservation:

$$\begin{align*}
1C\,V_\text{O}+2C\,V_\text{O}&=2C\,V_4\\
1C\,V_4+2C\,V_4+2C\,V_4&=2C\,V_\text{O}+2C\,V_3\\
1C\,V_3+2C\,V_3+2C\,V_3&=2C\,V_4+2C\,V_2\\
1C\,V_2+1C\,V_2+2C\,V_2&=2C\,V_3+1C\,V_1\\\\\therefore\\\\
3\,V_\text{O}&=2\,V_4\\
5\,V_4&=2\,V_\text{O}+2\,V_3\\
5\,V_3&=2\,V_4+2\,V_2\\
4\,V_2&=2\,V_3+V_1
\end{align*}$$

That one is really easy to do by hand. But if you do a simultaneous solution for the above you will get: \$V_\text{O}=\frac1{16}V_1\$.

(You also get \$V_2=\frac{43}{128}V_1\$, \$V_3=\frac{11}{64}V_1\$, and \$V_4=\frac{3}{32}V_1\$.)

Answer (score 0):

This is how one could start it... but I like Jonk's method better.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWeU4t.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>